# System Setting's display brightness control disappearing when laptop battery is not present

Tags: settings, system

The Display brightness control shows up again (along with the choice to Dim the screen brightness), IF i plug my battery into the laptop.
I probably haven't noticed before.
In the case that the battery is NOT present,these controls are gone.
Is this normal behaviour?
If this is normal behaviour,is there a way to have these controls back,even if the battery is not present?
Is there some way to have them constantly showing up?
Thanks in advance and congrats to the Team for this outstanding distro!!

Comment: This was changed couple of days ago because if the brightness control is not useable (e.g. on desktops) it freezes the plug. The workaround is to check if a battery is present.
Please file a bug report. 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/switchboard-plug-power/+bugs?orderby=-id&start=0